# Riak KV 2.1.1 Java Client: No suitable method found for Client.execute ()

Tags: java, riak, riak-search

I am using Java client for Riak KV 2.1.1. After creating index and applying it to Namespace, I am getting the no suitable method found error even though I am following the documentation given on the [website](http://docs.basho.com/riak/kv/2.2.3/developing/usage/search/). 
What is the solution for this?

Thanks.

Please see the code and the full error below.

```
        YokozunaIndex famousIndex = new YokozunaIndex("famous", "_yz_default");
        StoreIndex storeIndex = new StoreIndex.Builder(famousIndex)
                .build();
        client.execute(storeIndex);    
        Namespace streets=new Namespace("streets");
        StoreBucketPropsOperation storePropsOp = new StoreBucketPropsOperation.Builder(streets)
                .withSearchIndex("famous")
                .build();
        client.execute(storePropsOp); // this is where I am getting error
```

[image: Error Image]

Answer (score 2):

This is a documentation bug. `RiakClient.execute()` accepts an instance of `RiakCommand`, while `StoreBucketPropsOperation` is a lower-level API.

Instead, use the `StoreBucketProperties` command as follows:

```java
    StoreBucketProperties storePropsCommand = new StoreBucketProperties.Builder(streets)
            .withSearchIndex("famous")
            .build();
    client.execute(storePropsCommand);
```

Comment: Yeah I tried that before posting the question, it won't give you the error but my Search query is not working after applying index. Its a simple key value (string, string) bucket. it gives may error.  "Query cannot be completed".---------------------------------

SearchOperation searchOp = new SearchOperation
                    .Builder(BinaryValue.create("famous"), "My home *")
                    .build();
cluster.execute(searchOp);
List<Map<String, List<String>>> results = searchOp.get().getAllResults();

Comment: This is not what you asked. Actually, your original question is not even related to querying, but to associating an index with a bucket. As I explained, you should use the command API, which works in the same way as the operation API. If you have a different problem, post a different question.